# ERROR: Open failure for (zip file) during attempt to create a local file

Tags: sas, zip

My coworker and I have three zip files, representing three iterations of a monthly download from CMS of the NPPES Data Dissemination (March, April, and May). We use the following code to extract what we need from the newest zip file and create a fairly compact dataset.

```
PROC IMPORT OUT=NPI_Layout 
        DATAFILE= "&dir./NPI File Layout.xlsx" 
        DBMS=XLSX REPLACE;
 SHEET="Sheet1";
RUN;

options compress = yes;
data npi_layout;
  set npi_layout;
        length infmt fmt inpt $60. lbl $200.;
        if type = 'NUMBER' then do;
              infmt = 'informat '||compress(field)||' '||compress(length)||'.;';
              fmt = 'format '||compress(field)||' '||compress(length)||'.;';
              inpt = compress(field);
        end;
        else if type = 'VARCHAR' then do;
              infmt = 'informat '||compress(field)||' $'||compress(length)||'.;';
              fmt = 'format '||compress(field)||' $'||compress(length)||'.;';;
              inpt = compress(field)||' $';
        end;
        else if type = 'DATE' then do;
              infmt = 'informat '||compress(field)||' mmddyy10.;';
              fmt = 'format '||compress(field)||' date9.;';
              inpt = compress(field);
        end;
        lbl = 'label '||compress(field)||" = '"||trim(label)||"';";
run;
proc sql noprint;
  select      infmt
              ,fmt
              ,inpt
              ,lbl
  into  :infmt1 - 
              ,:fmt1 - 
              ,:inpt1 -
              ,:lbl1 - 
  from  npi_layout;
quit;
%macro loop;
  %let infmt_stmnt = ;
  %let fmt_stmnt = ;
  %let inpt_stmnt = input;
  %let lbl_stmnt = ;
  %do i = 1 %to &sqlobs;
        %let infmt_stmnt = &infmt_stmnt &&infmt&i;
        %let fmt_stmnt = &fmt_stmnt &&fmt&i;
        %let inpt_stmnt = &inpt_stmnt &&inpt&i;
        %let lbl_stmnt = &lbl_stmnt &&lbl&i;
  %end;
  data npi.npi;
        %let _EFIERR_ = 0; /* set the ERROR detection macro variable */
        infile inzip(npidata_pfile_20050523-20180513.csv)
        delimiter = ',' MISSOVER DSD lrecl = 32767 firstobs = 2;* obs = 10000;
        &infmt_stmnt;
        &fmt_stmnt;
        &inpt_stmnt;
        &lbl_stmnt;
  run;
%mend loop;
%loop;
```

When we run the above code on the file from March, we get a successful output. However, when we try to run it on the April and May downloads, we get the following error:

Error in Log

```
ERROR: Open failure for
*dir*/NPI/Downloads/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_May_2018.zip
during attempt to create a local file handle.
```

Google only returns a single result, which indicates that it's an error that pops up when a filename (or path, presumably) is wrong. We've double-checked the path and filename multiple times, and it's all correct (and, obviously, the code works on the March file). Additionally, if I change the code so it's trying to pull a non-existent .csv from the zip file, it gives me a different error about that file not existing within the zip, so it's clearly seeing the zip file in the first place. We're not really sure what's going on; any advice?

(The data is sourced from http://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPI_Files.html, if you want to check the file for yourself.)

Comment: What is the filename statement for inzip ? Does the zip file exhibit any errors if opened with other tools such as Windows File Explorer or 7zip ?

Comment: Can you show the layout information contained in "NPI File Layout.xlsx"  I'm guessing it's around 328 rows and transcribed in some manner from "NPPES Data Dissemination_Public File- Readme.pdf"

Comment: No issues with the file that I can see, and yes, it's a table version of the pdf. It's 329 rows by 8 columns; I'm not sure how to add the file itself here, though.

Comment: Ran into similar problem. Any updates or SAS forum discussion taking place?

Comment: No, unfortunately. After some back and forth with the SAS Support team, it mysteriously cleared up and hasn't been happening since. We're not sure if it was a resource limitation or file corruption or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding quotes around the member name?

```
infile inzip("npidata_pfile_20050523-20180513.csv") ...
```

Comment: Yes. Also, as I mentioned, it works on the March file--just not April or May.

Answer (score 0):

Saw the same ERROR message on Windows 10 64-bit with plenty of RAM and disk space.

The Windows internals used by the ZIP engine is likely dealing with streams which involves file handles.  So I would suspect the ZIP engine is trying to allocate too much RAM or too large an intermediary file for dealing with extracting the 6GB "npidata_pfile_20050523-20180513.csv".

Submit the issue to SAS Support -- There might be some session settings that would let the engine work against the file.  If not, you'll have to extract the file outside SAS.

How large were the April and May pfile sizes?

Comment: April and May are ~6.5 - 6.6 GB. March is ~6.4 GB.

Comment: A ceteris paribus conundrum indeed.